# Simplifying $4m^2n + 5mn^2 - 2m^2n + mn^2 - 3mn^2$. Why is the answer $2m^2n + 3mn^2$ instead of $2m^2 + 3m$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Simplify
$$4m^2n + 5mn^2 - 2m^2n + mn^2 - 3mn^2$$

My answer was $2m^2 + 3m$, but checking the answer at the back of my textbook showed that it was $2m^2n + 3mn^2$, and checking an online simplification calculator gave me the same answer.

My steps were roughly:
$$- 4m^2n + 5mn^2 - 2m^2n + mn^2 - 3mn^2$$
$$- 4m^2n + 5mn^2 + - 2m^2n + mn^2 + - 3mn^2$$
$$- (4m^2n + - 2m^2n) + (5mn^2 + mn^2 + -3mn^2)$$

Up to this point, my working seemed to be in line with the calculator I checked, except, I did not subtract $n$ from $(4m^2n + - 2m^2n)$ - My question is, **why does the answer only include one n?**

Shouldn’t it either be zero or two? Zero, if $n$ in $4m^2n$ is subtracted by $n$ in $2m^2n$, or two, if only $2m^2$ is negative?

The question is from p. 1 of the Pearson Edexcel International A-Level student book, and I’m not very proficient in mathematics. Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is $4a+5b-2a+b-3b$ in form

Comment: It is a great help to rewrite this sum, using $a=m^2n$, $b=mn^2$, as Paul says. Then it is obvious that the result is $2a+3b$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Proceeding to simplify

$$4m^2n + 5mn^2 - 2m^2n + mn^2 - 3mn^2$$

Reordering

$$4m^2n - 2m^2n + 5mn^2  + mn^2 - 3mn^2$$

Like-terms

$$(4m^2n - 2m^2n) + (5mn^2  + mn^2 - 3mn^2)$$

Coefficients

$$(4-2)m^2n + (5+1-3) mn^2$$

Arithmetic

$$2m^2n + 3 mn^2$$